# Export HDFS file with custom delimiter into Mysql via Sqoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

- I have file like this:

  ```
  1^%~binod^*~1^%~ritesh^*~1^%~shisir^*~1^%~budhdha^*~1^%~romika^*~1^%~rubeena^*~
  ```
- Where --input-fields-terminated-by '^%~' --input-lines-terminated-by '^*~'.
- I tried to export via command:

  ```
  sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoop --username root -P --table makalu --export-dir sqoop/makalu --input-fields-terminated-by '^%~' --input-lines-terminated-by '^*~'
  ```
- But it writes a single line of:

```
id|name
1|%~binod
```

in MySQL.

- Now my question is what would be the command to solve this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

arguments **--input-fields-terminated-by** and **--input-lines-terminated-by** accepts single character

when you execute your export command in terminal you can see below warnings

```
02/03 18:55:21 WARN sqoop.SqoopOptions: Character argument ^%~ has multiple characters; only the first will be used.
15/02/03 18:55:21 WARN sqoop.SqoopOptions: Character argument ^*~ has multiple characters; only the first will be used.
```

### Update:

One thing that I have observed is if lines are terminated other than \n or new line, then its only inserting one record into the database when you export. I tried couple of combination with field and line termination but only in case of line is terminated with \n data is exported into RDBMS table

Even tried with **--input-lines-terminated-by** and **--lines-terminated-by** arguments but no luck.

I have tested this on

```
Cloudera CDH-5.0.0-1
Sqoop version: 1.4.4-cdh5.0.0
```

Only thing that I'm able to find is [this](http://grokbase.com/t/sqoop/user/125hn62efq/sqoop-export-using-non-new-line-row-delimiter).

Comment: Even in my case of input:
1%binod^1%ritesh^1%shisir^1%budhdha^1%romika^1%rubeena^

And command:
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoop --username root -P --table makalu --export-dir sqoop/makalu --input-fields-terminated-by '%' --input-lines-terminated-by '^'
Shows error: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: 'null' and outputs:
id|name
1|binod
In MySQL.

Now what would be the solution to export all those data.

Answer (score 0):

The argument --input-fields-terminated-by 'any delimiter in single quotes'   works. Also do not use --direct in this case as then it overrides the delimiter. 
Obviously you would need a table created in mysql whose default delimited is ','